# Remove update messages for deactivated plugins

Tags: plugins, updates

Is it possible to hide just update messages for deactivated plugins in WP 3.4+?

Comment: yes, it is possible (answer above), but that doesn't address the problem. a plugin, even deactivated, can pose a security issue if left out of date. if you don't need the plugin, best to remove it from the site all together.

Answer (score 6):

Yep Its possible if you hook a function to `site_transient_update_plugins` filter hook and check if plugin is activated using `is_plugin_active` like this:

```
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_update_nag_for_deactivated');
function remove_update_nag_for_deactivated($value) {
    foreach($value->response as $key => $val){
        if (!is_plugin_active($val))
            unset($value->response[ $key]);
    }   
    return $value;
}
```